# Get dynamically generated value from redux-form state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I have created a form which has two levels of hierarchy.

```
-rate-card
  -rules-within-a-rate-card
```

User can create as many `rate-cards` with ten rules each or less.

I used [redux-form](https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/docs/api/reduxform.md/) to create a form which dynamically generates the cards and the value which are stored are in this form:

```
form: {
rateCardForm: {
  syncErrors: {
    mode: 'Required',
    networkBank: 'Required',
    paymentGateway: 'Required',
    onus: 'Required',
    lowerLimit: 'Required',
    upperLimit: 'Required',
    creditCycle: 'Required',
    percent: 'Required',
    flatFee: 'Required',
    tax: 'Required'
  },
  values: {
    'rate-card-0': {
      'rule-0': {
        mode: 'WALLET',
        networkBank: 'JCB',
        paymentGateway: 'All/Remaining',
        onus: true,
        lowerOperator: '>',
        lowerLimit: '123',
        upperOperator: '<=',
        upperLimit: '123',
        creditCycle: '12311',
        percent: '231',
        flatFee: '231',
        tax: '2311'
      },
      'rule-1': {
        mode: 'Cash',
        networkBank: 'JCB',
        paymentGateway: 'ICICI',
        onus: true,
        lowerOperator: '>',
        lowerLimit: '123',
        upperOperator: '<',
        upperLimit: '44554',
        creditCycle: '43',
        percent: '23',
        flatFee: '23',
        tax: '12'
      },
      dateRange: {
        startDate: '2019-03-14T06:30:00.000Z',
        endDate: '2019-04-15T06:30:00.000Z'
      }
    },
    'rate-card-1': {
      dateRange: {
        startDate: '2019-03-10T06:30:00.000Z',
        endDate: '2019-03-22T06:30:00.000Z'
      },
      'rule-0': {
        mode: 'UPI',
        networkBank: 'MASTERCARD',
        paymentGateway: 'HDFC',
        onus: true,
        lowerOperator: '>=',
        lowerLimit: '2323',
        upperOperator: '<',
        upperLimit: '123',
        creditCycle: '123',
        percent: '123',
        flatFee: '23',
        tax: '123'
      }
    }
  },
  anyTouched: true,
  submitSucceeded: true
}
```

I am dynamically generating the names for each rate card and for each rule (generated within a rate card).

I wish to access these names of the field in the component itself to conditionally render some fields based on some field selection.

What I am trying right now:

1. use `formValueSelector` decorator
2. getting the whole chunk of `values` key into the component

How do I get one value for one rate card and one rule only?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own selectors to get the data you need (a selector is nothing more than a function that takes the Redux state and returns a derived value). For instance, to get the ID's of all rate cards:

```js
function getRateCardNames(state) {
  return Object.keys(state.form.rateCardForm.values)
}
```

To get the rule names for a rate card:

```js
function getRuleNames(state, { rateCardName }) {
  return Object.keys(state.form.rateCardForm.values[rateCardName])
}
```

To get all fields for a specific rule:

```js
function getRuleValues(state, { rateCardName, ruleName }) {
  const rateCardValues = state.form.rateCardForm.values[rateCardName]
  return rateCardValues && rateCardValues[ruleName]
}
```

You can then call these selectors from your form component's `mapStateToProps`.

Comment: How would I know `ruleName` or how do I pass this as a prop to my component?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for. You asked: "How do I get one value for one rate card and one rule only?" I took that to mean "given a rate card and rule ID, how to I get the matching field values?" Did you mean something else?